# Jquery Datepicker dateformat issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

Here is my javascript snippet for date picker

```
jQuery.fn.dateWidget = function(settings){
    // default settings
    defaults = {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: Date.format,
        duration: '',
        showOn: 'button',
        showAnim: '',
        buttonText: Resources['common.button.selectdate'],
        buttonImage: Resources['appUrl'] + 'core/images/datePicker.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true               
    };

    // overwrite the defaults with provided settings
    settings = $.extend(defaults, settings); 

    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker(settings);
    });
};
```

Our application is localized and the Date.Format value is set from a properties file. It works perfectly but whenever a date format contains yyyy its generating year twice like 20142014-05-02 if date format is yyyy-mm-dd(swedish locale date format).

For yy-mm-dd dateformat datepicker gives 2014-05-02 but it breaks our application in other areas.

Am new to javascript, I dont really have any idea how to fix this. Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Dateformat can be any form like d/m/yyyy or d/yyyy/mm. I am a novice js programmer. I tried to replace yyyy with yy but i couldnt get it working for all the formats. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that gets Date.Format and replaces `yyyy` with `yy`` and returns the result. Use that function instead of Date.Format